# PickerView make individual colors for rows

Tags: ios, text, colors, uipickerview, uicolor

So what I want, is to make individual colors for my rows in a PickerView, but I really don't know how to do this. And it would also be cool to know how to make indivial textcolors.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If so, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are checking the `UIPickerView datasource`, you will find the following method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

I guess you can use it in order to modify the view in your `pickerView` by processing something like this:

- Initiate your `pickerView`

In your `viewDidLoad`for example:

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 4, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

- Call the desired method and make your changes:

Example:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIView *customRow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
switch (row) {
    case 0:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return customRow;
        break;

    case 1:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        return customRow;

    case 2:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        return customRow;

    case 3:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        return customRow;

    case 4:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        return customRow;

    case 5:
        customRow.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        return customRow;

    default:
        return nil;
        break;
    }
}
```

- Do not forget the required method in your implementation:

In your controller:

```
#pragma mark: UIPickeView datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 6;
}
```